# get/post web service from db in java

Tags: java, android, web-services, sqlite, restful-url

Hi I am writing a web server to be hosted locally that will have latitude and longitude posted in the URL/URI from an android device and this will be used as search criteria in an SQL Select query to retrieve the 5 clostes train stations.

I have made the code work with the hard coded Longitude and Latitude but now need to add in the functionality of it being dynamically added form teh adnroid device using the Post/Get functions, unfortunately i have never used get/post so dont know where to start.

Below is my code from all Classes in the web server, as said it all works hardcoded but now needs to accept input from an android device and return the same expected results. Thanks

```
public class WebServer {

    static String jArray = "";
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        try{

            HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080),0);
            server.createContext("/",new HttpHandler(){

                public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException{



                        try {
                            jArray = sqlConnector.train(jArray);
                        } catch (Throwable e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(he.getResponseBody()));
                    System.out.println("Processing Request");
                    he.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
                    String output = "<html><head></head><body><p>" + jArray + "</p></body></html>";
                    bw.write(output);
                    bw.close();
                }
            });
            server.start();
            System.out.println("Started up . . .");
        }
        catch (IOException ioe){
            System.err.println("problems Starting Webserver: " + ioe);
        }

    }

}

public class sqlConnector {

    public static String train(String jArray) throws Exception{
        PreparedStatement s = null;
        try 
        {
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Colin/trainstations.db");
            s = c.prepareStatement("SELECT Latitude, Longitude, StationName,( 3959 * acos(cos(radians(53.4355)) * cos(radians(Latitude)) * cos(radians(Longitude) - radians(-3.0508)) + sin(radians(53.4355)) * sin(radians(Latitude )))) AS distance FROM stations ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0,5;");
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery();
            jArray = jsonConverter.convertResultSetIntoJSON(rs, jArray);

        }
        catch (SQLException se)
        {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jArray;

    }
}

public class jsonConverter {

    public static String convertResultSetIntoJSON(ResultSet rs, String jArray) throws Exception {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        while (rs.next()) {
            int total_rows = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            for (int i = 0; i < total_rows; i++) {
                String columnName = rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i + 1).toString();
                Object columnValue = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                obj.put(columnName, columnValue);
            }
            jsonArray.put(obj);
        }
        jArray = jsonArray.toString();
        return jArray;
    }
```

}

I am currently connected to another webserver that hosts the same data and is fully functinal and after the port number its format is as follows

```
/stations?lat=" + lat + "&lng=" + lng);
```

where lat and lng are my variable taken using GPS

Answer (score 0):

The process would be like this:

1) Parse the Parameters from query String he.getRequestURI().getQuery()

```
  /**
   * returns the url parameters in a map
   * @param query
   * @return map
   */
  public static Map<String, String> queryToMap(String query){
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String param : query.split("&")) {
        String pair[] = param.split("=");
        if (pair.length>1) {
            result.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
        }else{
            result.put(pair[0], "");
        }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

2) Pass these parameters into select method

```
 public static String train(String jArray, double lat, double long) throws Exception{
```

3) Use it in your statement

```
s = c.prepareStatement("SELECT Latitude, Longitude, StationName,
        ( 3959 * acos(cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(Latitude))
      * cos(radians(Longitude) - radians(?)) + sin(radians(?))
      * sin(radians(Latitude )))) 
   AS distance FROM stations ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0,5;");
s.setDouble(1, lat);
s.setDouble(2, long);
s.setDouble(3, lat);
```

And finally

4) Fix your code.

- use a Database connection pool instead of connecting to the database for every call
- use try-with-resource to automatically close ResultSet, PreparedStatement, Connection (even in case of Errors)

Hope that helps as a rough guideline :-)